# SQL Select with case - select into multiple groups

Tags: sql, case

I have a list of countries and a columns of normalized income as follows:

```
  country income
  --------------
  es    500
  gb    200
  sg    300
  id    500
  de    450
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to break out the countries into different geographic regions and a global region.

The EU region would contain es (Spain), gb (Great Britain) and de (Germany).
The Asia region would contain sg (Singapore) and id (Indonesia)

Now I also want to add each country into a Global geographic region, so the Global region would contain *all* the countries listed above

So this would make es (Spain) fall under both EU and Global

Similarly id (Indonesia) would fall under both Asia and Global

The resulting table would be like this:

```
   region    country income
   -------------------------
   EU        es    500
   EU        gb    200
   ASIA      sg    300
   ASIA      id    500
   EU        de    450
   Global    es    500
   Global    gb    200
   Global    sg    300
   Global    id    500
   Global    de    450
```

I was thinking of something on the lines of a CASE statement

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN country IN ('es', 'gb', 'de') 
            THEN 'EU'
         WHEN country IN ('id', 'sg') 
            THEN 'ASIA'
```

But I'm not sure how to get the Global group from here. This doesn't *have* to be done via a CASE statement - open to suggestions.

Comment: what platform are you using?  oracle, db2, sql server, mysql, something else?

Comment: I'm currently using MySQL but I'm looking for a product-agnostic solution as this could be ported over to Oracle or Vertica at any point.

Comment: mysql is basically incompatable with everything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT
    CASE when country in ('es', 'gb', 'de') THEN 'EU'
         when country in ('id', 'sg') THEN 'ASIA'
         END as Region, country,income FROM country

         UNION
 SELECT 'Global',country,income 
          FROM country
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with group assignment:

```
select reg.region, reg.country, income
from country c join
     (select 'es' as country, 'EU' as region union all
      select 'gb' as country, 'EU' as region union all
      select 'de' as country, 'EU' as region union all
      select 'id' as country, 'EU' as region union all
      select 'sg' as country, 'EU' as region union all
      select 'es' as country, 'GLOBAL' as region union all
      select 'gb' as country, 'GLOBAL' as region union all
      select 'de' as country, 'GLOBAL' as region union all
      select 'id' as country, 'GLOBAL' as region union all
      select 'sg' as country, 'GLOBAL' as region
     ) as reg
     on c.country = reg.country;
```

I would be inclined to put the country/region mapping into a separate table.

Comment: I got a call so I missed giving my answer but I would have used `VALUES` instead of `UNION ALL` Is there a reason not to use VALUES?

Comment: @Hogan . . . Because the question is not tagged with either SQL Server or Postgres

Comment: to DB2 or Oracle.  VALUES was in the sql standard years ago.